# who is reading logback.xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, logback, slf4j

Good day,

I have a existing Java web application host by websphere developed by senior, that using `org.slf4j.Logger` for logging. And I found that I have a `logback.xml` in my workspace, I do some changes on the `logback.xml` and its take effect.

However, I am curious which file is reading this `logback.xml`, I search for whole workspace, didnt found any place that is point to `logback.xml`.

I try to google on this, some is code to read this file, but didnt see any case like mine.

It it read by the the `org.slf4j.Logger` jar file?

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

You're already looking to the right direction. The configuration is read by logback (how this is done is described on a high-level here [at the logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)). So the loading of the configuration happens in logback but not in slf4j (which is "just" a facade for different logging frameworks like log4j or in your case logback) as you suspected. Find some more details about SLF4J and the relation to logback [here](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping).

Hope that makes it a little more clear.